# Catch the end of drawing in OL6

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6, angular-openlayers

I have this code which is complaining after upgrading to OL6.6.1

```
 draw.on('drawend', (e: olDrawEvent) => {
  const format: olGeoJson = new olGeoJson();
  this.shapeString = format.writeGeometry(e.feature.getGeometry(),
    { dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857', rightHanded: false });
  this.featureGeometry = e.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  if (!this.cancelClick) {
    this.savePolygon(this.featureGeometry[0]);
  }
});
```

I'm getting an error on 'drawend' which says...

> No overload matches this call.
> The last overload gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '("error" | "change" | "propertychange" | "change:active" | "drawstart" | "drawend" | "drawabort")[]'.ts(2769)

...and an error on e.feature which says

> Property 'feature' does not exist on type 'Draw'

For drawend I see that it is still available, I have no idea what's breaking, why, and how to fix it.  For e.feature  olDrawEvent seems like the wrong object to use but so does olDraw??  I don't understand what OpenLayers wants me to do here and there are no examples to show similar functionality that I can find?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing your Draw and DrawEvent like I was...

```
import olDraw from 'ol/interaction/Draw.js';
import olDrawEvent from 'ol/interaction/Draw';
```

change your import to...

```
import  Draw, { DrawEvent }  from 'ol/interaction/Draw';
```

and change all objects to the new instances.